# How to use "Infatuation" in correct way?

Tags: word-usage

As infatuation means attraction for someone for short-time. So is it correct to say "he has always been my infatuation"? Can I use "always" in that sentence. Or is it correct "I have always been infatuated with him." Again here can I use "always"?

Comment: Hello, Lucia. You need to show research here.  Do the definitions given by [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/infatuation), [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infatuation) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/infatuation) agree that infatuations cannot be other than short-lived? If so, you can't use 'always'. If the definitions disagree on this, you have to decide whether you are happy using an arguable usage.

Comment: I suggest that while many, if not most infatuations do last for only a shohrt time that's pure co-incidence… it's not related to the naturre of infatuation, though it might be affected by the social circumstances surrounding the people…

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the MW definition of [infatuate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infatuate):

> 1 : to cause to be foolish : deprive of sound judgment
>
> 2 : to inspire with a foolish or extravagant love or admiration

The notable thing about an infatuation vs "real" affection is not the duration but the foolishness of it.  Short duration is just one possible sign of this.

Answer (score -1):

In common spoken English, it's more common to say "He/she is infatuated with him/her" rather than name someone as the infatuation, it's just not done and gives a very objective tone.

So you'd probably say "I've always been infatuated with him"  however it's important to note that if you've always been infatuated, then it's not short term and it's not infatuation.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/infatuation) says: "*3: an object of foolish or extravagant passion*" Although it marks this usage as British. (Not that I have ever heard it used that way. But then, maybe no one has ever been infatuated with me.)